# Radio Button update

Tags: android, bluetooth, radio-button

I am developing an application which needs to connect to an embedded bluetooth device, and then send data back and forth between my android device and the embedded chip. I currently have followed the model given in the BluetoothChat example, and I am very close to connecting properly. For error checking, I was wondering if there was a way to have a Radio Button/Checkbox/something that could be attached to a boolean, so that after connecting with a device the box would become checked, but if no connection could be made, it was left unchecked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the built-in Checkbox widget.

Suppose you have the boolean isConnected used to track the BT connection, then set the checkbox state by:

```
checkBox.setChecked(isConnected);
```